# Toggle animate with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to toggle the animation, I want every time i click on the class (message) the other class (.message2 and down-box2) martin top and when i click again on the same class (Message) it return again to the default css.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".down-box").hide();
    });
 $(".message").click(function(){
 $(".down-box").toggle();
 $(".message2").animate({"marginTop":"+310px"});
 $(".down-box2").animate({"marginTop":"+370px"}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: just keep the status in a attribute or a var and check to animate or remove the css margin-top

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. It will sure help you.

```js
var $div = $('#div')
$('button').click(function() {
  $div.toggleClass('isOut')
  var isOut = $div.hasClass('isOut')
  $div.animate({marginTop: isOut ? '30%' : '0'}, 300)
})
```

```css
#div{
    background:blue;
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: can you make it by jquery?

Answer (score 0):

> **check working snippet**

```js
$("#arrow_container").click( function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
  $("#nav").stop().animate({marginTop:"-100px"}, 200);          
    } else {
        $("#nav").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("isDown");
 return false;
});
```

```css
#nav {
width: 250px;
height: 115px;
margin: -100px 0px 0px -webkit-calc(100% - 280px);
position: absolute;
background:red;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
</div>

<button id="arrow_container">click</button>
```

> check this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".down-box").hide();
        $(".message").toggle(function () {
            $(".down-box").show();
           $(".message2").animate({"marginTop":"310px"});
           $(".down-box2").animate({"marginTop":"370px"}); 
            return false;
        },
        function () {
            $(".down-box").hide();
           $(".message2").animate({"marginTop":"0px"});
           $(".down-box2").animate({"marginTop":"0px"}); 

            return false;
        });

})
```

Comment: it does animate once i open the page

Comment: check snippet above